# Open file with formatted variable name in Julia

Tags: file, formatting, julia

I have a list of files numbered gll_01.tab, gll_02.tab, ...., gll_20.tab in a subdirectory of my parent directory. These files are tabular data files.

I want to open/read files with user-specified input.

I can do:

```
a = 3
open("directory/gll_0$a.tab")
```

But using this approach, I would have to define two separate variable names for (01 to 09) and for (10 to 18). How can I use variables or strings with name 02, 03, ..., etc?

In python, I can have an equivalent command:

```
a = 4
g = '{:02d}'.format(a)
f = open('directory/gll_%s.tab' %g)
```

Is there an equivalent string formatting command in Julia?

Comment: A general solution is to use a specialized package, e.g. https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl. However in this case `lpad` will be sufficient: `"directory/gll_$(lpad(a,2,"0")).tab"`.

Comment: Thanks. 'lpad' is exactly what I was looking for. You could add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple answer in this case would be to use `lpad`:

```
a = 3
open("directory/gll_$(lpad(a,2,"0")).tab")
```

If you need more fancy formatting you can use e.g. https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl, in this case this would be:

```
using Formatting
a = 3
open("directory/gll_$(fmt("0>2", a)).tab")
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `@sprintf`, [docs are here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/#Printf.@sprintf). With that you can use `%02d` as a formatting option that would pad a digit `d` to length `2` with `0`s preceding it:

```
julia> using Printf # this is in the standard library
julia> @sprintf("directory/gll_%02d.tab", 1)
"directory/gll_01.tab"
```

You can use this in your open statements too. Here they are in action:

```
julia> for i in 5:10
           println("$i file is: $(@sprintf("directory/gll_%02d.tab",i))")
       end
5 file is: directory/gll_05.tab
6 file is: directory/gll_06.tab
7 file is: directory/gll_07.tab
8 file is: directory/gll_08.tab
9 file is: directory/gll_09.tab
10 file is: directory/gll_10.tab
```